# Appium tests on Amazon device farm getting stuck in custom test environment stuck at npm install *.tgz

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

I have android tests written in webdriverIO, appium. Running fine on my local machine. But on Amazon device farm execution getting stuck in custom test environment at npm install *.tgz.
Tech stack selected on amazon device farm: node 14.19.1 appium 1.22.2

```js
# Phases are collection of commands that get executed on Device Farm.
phases:
  # The install phase includes commands that install dependencies that your tests use.
  # Default dependencies for testing frameworks supported on Device Farm are already installed.
  install:
    commands:
      # By default the Node.js version installed is 11.4.0, however we enable you to change it
      # using the Node version manager (nvm). An example "nvm" command below changes the version to 14.19.1
      - export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm
      - . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
      - nvm install 14.19.1

      # Unpackage and install the node modules that you uploaded in the test phase.
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - npm install *.tgz
      
      # This test execution environment uses Appium version 1.9.1 by default, however we enable you to change it using
      # the Appium version manager (avm). An example "avm" command below changes the version to 1.22.2.
      # For your convenience, we have preinstalled the following versions: 1.22.2, 1.19.0, 1.18.3, 1.18.1, 1.18.0, 1.17.1, 1.16.0, 1.15.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.1, and 1.13.0.
      # To use one of these Appium versions, change the version number in the "avm" command below to your desired version:
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.22.2
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js

  # The pre-test phase includes commands that setup your test environment.
  pre_test:
    commands:
      # We recommend starting appium server process in the background using the command below.
      # Appium server log will go to $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR directory.
      # The environment variables below will be auto-populated during run time.
      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\",
        \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\",
        \"chromedriverExecutable\":\"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  # The test phase includes commands that start your test suite execution.
  test:
    commands:
      # Go into the root folder containing your source code and node_modules
      - echo "Navigate to test source code"
      # Change the directory to node_modules folder as it has your test code and the dependency node modules.
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/node_modules/*

      - echo "Start Appium Node test"
      # Enter the command below to start the tests . The comamnd should be similar to what you use to run the tests locally.
      # For e.g. assuming you run your tests locally using command "node YOUR_TEST_FILENAME.js.", enter the same command below:
      - npm run test:adf:android

  # The post test phase includes are commands that are run after your tests are executed.
  post_test:
    commands:

# The artifacts phase lets you specify the location where your tests logs, device logs will be stored.
# And also let you specify the location of your test logs and artifacts which you want to be collected by Device Farm.
# These logs and artifacts will be available through ListArtifacts API in Device Farm.
artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```

I followed this blog to setup amazon device farm [set up amazon device farm](https://medium.com/jetclosing-engineering/react-native-device-testing-w-appium-node-and-aws-device-farm-295081129790#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjU4MGFkYjBjMzJhMTc1ZDk1MGExYzE5MDFjMTgyZmMxNzM0MWRkYzQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.kh2zndGehwg1zRsXkT-CgW2BqjR0u2yRdss_iWpwxGnNWPbELy9gTUxO41HNA1v93v4G_mwjuUpAfBQdWarQH6FFw9-CfGZHIXiG_nMObBnojsmML3mv_sPAohQOvXt_9WVUrm_7Zs3kxxwCjk6xNoHEQUHhDzxHqGTaqzzEDKarmnZnpMBeiwH4Sx653ex0iSiZ8ShUHmigKT0q6LmqUaUyFx7m178dEHdREGK0OY9B1wm6Hy14Hlw8qYs2kSh4LYajjOiQ67V_wF-hv7s-QzIX1zLGZI89PXvVZO4COwBsb1ZYJFvcukDyXJ5C46ULUmNu3kw1aghx8YJx88ab1A)